# Ruby copying file

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby from learn ruby the hard way website (exercise 17).
I'm trying to copy a file into another file.
Instead of copying, it writes #.
Please help

```
puts "Hi, enter the file you'd like to copy"
from_file = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "What's the name of the file you'd like to have it overwritten"
to_file = $stdin.gets.chomp

puts "You want to copy #{from_file} into #{to_file}, right?"
$stdin.gets.chomp

puts "Contents of #{from_file}:"
first_file = open(from_file)
puts first_file.read

puts "Contents of #{to_file}:"
second_file = open(to_file)
puts second_file.read

puts "now overwriting"
first_file = open(second_file, 'w')
first_file.write(second_file)

puts "Contents of #{from_file}:"
first_file = open(from_file)
puts first_file.read

puts "Contents of #{to_file}:"
second_file = open(to_file)
puts second_file.read
```

Comment: I think you should find a better ruby tutorial now because, on SO, I've seen many awful code snippets that come from _Learn Ruby the Hard Way_.

Comment: Please  recommend me some if you know any.

Comment: @Aetherus I think this code snippet is the OP's attempt to solve the [exercise](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex17.html). I would be quite surprised if Zed A. Shaw would publish such code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to keep straight the difference between your *file names* and *file handles*. Also, the code is non-idiomatic Ruby. To read a file, someone coming from say PHP might write:

```
first_file = open(from_file)
first_file_contents = first_file.read
first_file.close

second_file = open(to_file, 'w')
second_file.write(first_file_contents)
second_file.close
```

This is valid Ruby, but not very Rubyish Ruby. Having learned about blocks, this is much better:

```
File.open(from_file) do |first_file|
  File.open(to_file, 'w') do |second_file|
    second_file.write(first_file.read)
  end
end
```

Getting to know the library a bit better, you might find this shortcut:

```
first_file_contents = File.read(from_file)
File.write(to_file, second_file_contents)
```

A bit more experience will give you this:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.copy_file(from_file, to_file)
```

EDIT: Thanks to Stefan for spotting a missing argument.